# DoCmd.RunSQL in Access not providing expected results

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I've done this a zillion times, and I don't know what's changed.

```
Private Sub Foo()
dim rst as DAO.Recordset
```

set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Select * From Table1;", dbOpenDynaset)
rst.movefirst

Do Until rst.EOF
DoCmd.RunSQL INSERT INTO Table2 (Last, First, Gender) VALUES (" & "' & rst!Last & '" & ", " & "' & rst!First & '" & ", " & "' & rst!Gender & '" & ");"
rst.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub

If I do this, the values inserted into Last, First and Gender are '" & rst!ColumnName &  "' versus the actual data from the column.

If I omit the single quotes it works until it comes across a last name with a hypen or aposttrophe and then it throws a syntax error.

But I've done this same thing in code a zillion times the last 6 years and it's always worked and for whatever reason on this new project it's not proving the results I am used to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have that a bit mixed up:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table2 (Last, First, Gender) VALUES ('" & _
  & rst!Last & "', '" & rst!First & "', '" & rst!Gender & "');"
```

Note that if you have names that contain apostrophes, the above will fail, so it is a good idea to escape them like so:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table2 (Last, First, Gender) VALUES ('" & _
  & Replace(rst!Last,"'","''") & "', '" & Replace(rst!First,"'","''") _
  & "', '" & rst!Gender & "');"
```

The other point that I wonder about is why are you doing this in steps? Why not:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table2 (Last, First, Gender) " _
       & "SELECT Last, First, Gender FROM Table1 "

CurrentDB.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Yeah I just typed this out real fast before picking my daughter up so I boobed up the apostrophes.  I'm *reasonably* sure I have it right at the office, but I'll check and come back tomorrow.

Comment: There's more processing I am doing behind scenes so this was just an example. Thanks.

Comment: If a string "rst!Gender" is being inserted into your table, I can assure you that the quotes are mixed up at the office as well.

Comment: None of them are getting inserted. Just the rst!Names.